# How do I fill a tm struct with my own values, then print them out?

Tags: c++, iomanip

I want to fill my tm struct with custom values for hours, minutes, and seconds, then use std::put_time() to output it.

my code is inside of a to_string function for a custom class that holds a date and time:

```
std::string Gregorian::to_string() const {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    struct std::tm *tmTime;

    //This is where I add my custom time values
    tmTime->tm_hour = hour_;
    tmTime->tm_min = minute_;
    tmTime->tm_sec = second_;   


    oss << civil::day_name( day_of_week( to_jd() ) ) << ", ";

    oss << gregorian_month_name( month_ ) << ' ' << (unsigned) day_ << ' ';
    if( year_ <= 0 )
        oss << (-year_ + 1) << " BCE";
    else
        oss << year_ << " CE, ";

    //i'm trying to use std::put_time here but it prints nothing
    oss << std::put_time(tmTime, "%r");

    return oss.str();
}
```

Am I missing something important? I have been reading about this online a lot. All of the examples I've seen use the local time to fill the tm struct (That's obviously not what I want to do).

So.. if hour_, minute_, and second_ all equal 0, I would like it to print 12:00:00 am

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: an example of what the output looks like:

```
"Wednesday, January 1 1000 CE, "
```

Where the space after 'CE,' is where the time should be.

Also, changing it to this:

```
struct std::tm tmTime;


    tmTime.tm_hour = hour_;
    tmTime.tm_min = minute_;
    tmTime.tm_sec = second_;
```

and:

```
oss << std::put_time(&tmTime, "%r");
```

gives me the same output. I forgot to mention that I tried that too.

Comment: Where is the problem? What output do you have?

Comment: Change `struct std::tm *tmTime;` to `struct std::tm tmTime;` and use `tmTime.tm_hour = hour_;` etc. You were writing to uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 2):

In this line,

```
struct std::tm *tmTime;
```

you have a pointer that hasn't been initialized. In the next few lines you are using the uninitialized pointer to access the members of the struct. That is cause for undefined behavior.

As suggested in a comment by  πάντα ῥεῖ, you need to use:

```
struct std::tm tmTime;
tmTime.tm_hour = hour_;
tmTime.tm_min = minute_;
tmTime.tm_sec = second_;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this wouldn't be working for me? This is the way I had it originally.

Comment: @kburlz, you should set the values of all the fields in `tmTime`. It's possible that `std::put_time` depends on the values of the other fields too.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu), that this should be working for you.
What compiler are you using? It's possible that you have an uninitialized `hour_`, `minute_`, or `second_`. Or it may be that `put_time` needs `tm_mday`, `tm_mon`, and `tm_year` set to legal values as well to output the time.

By way of comment it seems like you're doubling down on your year/month/day information. I think you should be able to do something like `put_time(tmTime, tmTime->tm_year > -1990 ? "%A, %B %e %Y AD, %r" : "%A, %B %e %Y BC, %r");`